# Loops not allowed on MongoDB Relational Migrator

Tags: mongodb, migration, schema-migration

Hi I'm trying to use MongoDB Relational Migrator to migrate my postgreSQL DB to MongoDB but I'm getting this message when I try to create a data migration job

> Error building job context: loops not allowed

I think this is related to a circular reference I have on one of my tables where a `Section` can have subsections referenced by `section_id` but I'm not even sure if this is the problem and how can I handle this kind of reference with MongoDB. Has anyone had this kind of message before? I'm trying to look for that message on the documentation but can't find anything related. Is there any way to exclude this kind of references temporarily in order to migrate most data and handle that manually?. Below is the picture of the error on the tool.

[image: MonogoDB Relational tool error]